# After deleting the UITableViewCell , a blank row appeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

First,I customized the `UITableViewCell` and put a new `label` into it；

Then I swiped the row and  deleted it (not the last one), and it to be deleted. unfortunately，the last one moved down and covered the new one appeared in the window,but leave a blank row, just like the image below;

[image]

Comment: Are you reloading your UITableView? Check your datasource change and reloading. Sorry cant help much on this.

Comment: Just put some code.... so Can review it

Comment: @user822646: I've up voted ur answer, so the reputation improve to make ur problem solved.

Comment: google it many times but no result

Comment: It might be possible that after deletion of a row, your UITableview is not getting refreshed and that's why it is continuing with the older numbers of row count. And also you have to reset your datasource and reload the UITableview.

Comment: yeah I just solve it by refreshing the tableview with the method [tableView reload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. numberOfRowsInSection is properly implemented - maybe you are getting the number of rows from an [array count] that still has the NSString in question;
2. You are calling reloadData

Comment: stackoverflow is really magical site , All my question is properly answered  thank you~~ thank you for Justin Skin's help~